# UIAlertView category : getting error

Tags: ios, uialertview, objective-c-category

How's it going, I'd like to use the `UIAlertView` category, but I'm getting an error `use of undeclared identifier UIAlertView` & `cannot find interface declaration for UIAlertView`. What I'm doing wrong?

**Here is.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIAlertView(error)

+(void)error:(NSString*)msg;

@end
```

**Here is .m**

```
#import "UIAlertView+error.h"

@implementation UIAlertView(error)
+(void)error:(NSString*)msg
{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                            message:msg
                           delegate:nil
                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                  otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
}
@end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a category on UIAlertView and UIAlertView is in UIKit, not Foundation. So

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Comment: @user7221 I would suggest you study up on some of the basics first.  Working with imports and frameworks is some of the most fundamental stuff you need to understand.  Documentation everywhere. Doesn't require SO.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to rethink your category using the UIAlertController, since UIAlertView is deprecated and can be removed at any time from now.

I crafted a simple category wrapper that mimic the UIAlertView behaviour to help this transition. You can get it from the following gist: [UIAlertController+Utilities](https://gist.github.com/valvoline/528922fd0e0865599dac)

And this is a simple refactoring of your method using the above category and a conditional if-statement to support iOS versions prior of 8.0:

```
+(void)error:(NSString*)msg
{
    if(([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"8.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)) {
        UIAlertController *ac = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                    message:msg
                                                                    actions:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Close"
                                                                                                     style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                                                                       //add your CLOSE instructions here
                                                                                                   }], nil];

        [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentViewController:ac animated:YES completion:^{
            //do whatever you want on presentation completition
        }];
    } else {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                    message:msg
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                          otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
    }
}
```